# Remove ubuntu by command

Tags: uninstall

I have problem with the system. Probably error. Want to remove ubuntu and reinstall it. I can just write in the terminal.  Can't open the computer... there is a command to remove ubuntu?  It will really help me if u know. .. tnx
Edit
I got massage that there is problem in the system.  I ignored it. After few minutes the computer stuck and opened terminal window that asked me to log in.  I log in. Don't know what I should do now since I can't go out from this window

Comment: What do you mean by "removing Ubuntu"? If your OS doesn't work, why don't just re-install it?

Comment: You can simply reinstall and choose to overwrite your previous install.  This is a horribly written question, it's quite impossible to answer it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Ubuntu is not a program and you will need to identify the problem, version of Ubuntu, and how you installed. I disagree with the other advice here, reinstalling is unlikely to resolve your problem. What did you do and what error messages are you getting?

Comment: I'm sorry. I installed ubuntu just before 2 days and I don't know the system yet. Will try to be more specific next time...

Comment: I think the problem you are having is that the Ubuntu Graphical User Interface doens't really launch at all, is that it? All that is appearing when you turn on the computer is a sort of Command Line Interface? Am I correct? In order to re-install Ubuntu, you need a Live-CD or Live-USB of Ubuntu. Do you have that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

What you try to do is not the way to "remove" Ubuntu. When you want to remove the whole system and reinstall it, boot from the Ubuntu installation media, select **Try Ubuntu without installing** and on the Live desktop, open **GParted**. Format the Ubuntu partition with ext4.

Close GParted and click on **Install Ubuntu**. When asked, choose **Something else**. Select the partition you have formatted before - select `/` (root) as mount point and `ext4` as format.
Start the installation and when finished, reboot into the new installed Ubuntu system.

Before reinstalling Ubuntu, you should try to find out what caused the problem. Maybe it can be fixed. Even if you want to reinstall the operating system, it is useful to know about it, mainly to avoid experiencing the same problems and issues again after reinstalling the Ubuntu system.

Comment: As we really do not know the nature of the problem, I disagree with blindly reinstalling. First the problem may be fixed without reinstalling and second it could be a hardware problem. The question is very low quality and this is better a comment then an answer.

Comment: I try to escape from the terminal window or turn off the computer but I can't.  Don't know how to go to the ubuntu installation media

Comment: I got massage that there is problem in the system.  I ignored it. After few minutes the computer stuck and now there are terminal window that asked me to log in.  I log in. Don't know what I should do now since I can't go out from this window

Comment: @ShuliSompo - How did you install ubuntu ? what version of ubuntu ? what hardware ? what errors ? this is the sort of information we need to know. I am sorry you are having a problem but simply stating you have a problem is insufficient information. Unless you edited system files reinstalling is unlikely to help.

Comment: @ShuliSompo : If you mean the "black virtual terminal console" on the login screen, enter your user name and the password and then type sudo poweroff to shutdown the PC. Also it is possible that you have an issue that will occur after reinstalling the system again. Please provide more hardware details, most important is the graphics adapter. :)

Comment: It worked. I'm out of this black virtual terminal console:) I'll try now to reinstall.  Thank u!

Comment: @cl-netbox - perfect